# install4j ExecuteLauncherAction in Unattended mode

Tags: java, install4j

I'm running our generated installer in Unattended mode (with -q and -splash "Title") showing a progress to the user.

At the end of the installation I'd like to launch the installed application, so I have added a ExecuteLauncherAction at the FinishedScreen with a preselected checkbox (to launch the application). But in unattended mode the application is not launched. The log shows this

```
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.InstallationScreen [ID 6]: Rollback barrier reached
       command: move 1 screens, executing actions, checking condition
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.FinishedScreen [ID 10]: Show screen
       Variable changed: executeLauncherAction=true[class java.lang.Boolean]
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.FinishedScreen [ID 10]: command: finish
       cleaning up
       Finished
```

Is there a way to force the installer in unattended mode to execute the launcher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the "Execute launcher" action to the "Finish" screen and answer the "Additional confirmation" question with "Yes", install4j adds a condition expression

```
context.getBooleanVariable("executeLauncherAction") && (!context.isUnattended())
```

to the action. You can change the "Condition expression" property to

```
context.getBooleanVariable("executeLauncherAction")
```

to execute the action in unattended mode as well.